# Is it a good idea to control notification (sound, new submissions and badge) inside your App

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I currently trying to implement a way to turn on / off push notification sound , badge and alert via inside App. Is this good practice? I am trying to do that now, but the App acts strangely doing this. Any tips or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Can you write some sample snippet how you are trying to modify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your are talking about remote server push notification, it actually depends if your app is running or not.

If not running the notification enable/disable setting lies entirely in hand of user and you can just recommend changes and redirect user to settings app. It cannot be changed manually.

Push noti has a param about badge and sound which can be controlled by ur server. Also updating the badge count programmatically once app gets chance to execute is regular practice I.e. to clear pending noti.

If running you can handle the notification or badge update as well as sound however you want.

Please check for details
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html

Answer (score 0):

I would say that probably the only things that you should try to manually manage would be notification badges and sounds. In fact, you're supposed to manage the badge counts. From Apple's documentation:

> The number to display as the badge of the application icon. If this property is absent, the badge is not changed. To remove the badge, set the value of this property to `0`.

In addition, they provide a nice little chart (right click it and view the image in a new tab for full resolution):

[image: Keys for APNs]

For sounds, the best way to do this might be to tell your server to send a notification with/without sound for X user. Notice:

> If the sound file doesn’t exist or default is specified as the value, the default alert sound is played.

Regarding managing other notification visuals such as the alert/banner, I wouldn't recommend trying to mess with that. Things like this should be left to the app's settings inside the phone's Settings application. After all, they have all these options:

[image: Settings screenshot]

Source: [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html)